# How skip a header in the next loop of writing data in csv file - Python

Tags: python, csv, schedule

I writting a script, where I dowload a data from json file (about temperature and data from datetime) and I want save the data i csv file. The script has a schedule set every minute to download new data from json. I have a problem with one thing.  Running the code causes the data to write correctly, but each time with a header. The question is how to save the header only once?

My script:
...

```
with open('Temp.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['Date', 'Temp']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Date':now, 'Temp':Temperatura})
```

My DataFrame look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9KHi.png)

but I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWGfH.png)

Thanks for help,
Dawid

Comment: Can't you just add the headers in yourself at the top and then not add them each time?

Comment: Unfortunately not because then I don't have a dictionary reference, and all the data is stored in one column in csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the header before the first row. So check the existence of the file to decide on writing the header.

```
import os 

file_exists = os.path.exists('Temp.csv')

with open('Temp.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['Date', 'Temp']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if not file_exists:
        writer.writeheader() # So the header is written only once just before the first row
    writer.writerow({'Date':now, 'Temp':Temperatura})
```

For the rest rows, since the csv file exists, header is not written again.

Comment: Thank you for helps. Your code will be correct when I use in row:

'if not file exists:' 
not
'if file exists:'

Thanks for hep all, best regards! :)

Comment: Yes it should be not file_exists. I made a mistake.